# Error installing mitmproxy

Tags: ubuntu, mitmproxy

every time i run sudo pip install mitmproxy, i get the following errors:

```
`Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-X64rxt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /home/rg/.pip/pip.log`
```

i have already tried:`sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` but still getting the error!

the log file has:
     ERROR: /bin/sh: 1: xslt-config: not found

```
** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
```

Comment: Posting the relevant parts of `/home/rg/.pip/pip.log` would give us a chance to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out where to obtain `xslt-config`, and install that first.

Comment: i  have got the problem sorted out! thanks btw!                   'sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev libxml2-dev' did the trick